# How to Force the User to Complete the Whole Form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

I am creating a Sing Up form. I need the user to complete every field of the form, but the rails only blocks the creation when there is no password. What I have to do to force the user to complete the whole form before submiting?

Here's my form code:

```
 <%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
  <% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :fav_team, "Favorite Team" %>
    <%= collection_select(:user, :fav_team, League.order(:name), :id, :name, {:include_blank => "Select a League"},  { :id => "leagues_select"}) %> 
    <%= grouped_collection_select(:user, :fav_team, League.order(:name), :teams, :name, :id, :name, {:include_blank => true}, {}) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :net_worth, "Net Worth (USD)" %>
    <%= f.text_field :net_worth, :readonly => true, :value => "100" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :country %>
    <%= f.select :country, options_for_Countrys, :include_blank => true %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Start by googling "client side validations"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write validations in your models to make sure the data is valid and present.

In your case you have to do something like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :first_name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :last_name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
end
```

[You can check here for more information](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Comment: OP is asking for client side validation, not server side, that is, to "*force the user to complete the whole form **before** submitting*".